# Merging xcode repositories on Xcode: getting rid of C's

Tags: xcode, git, merge, git-merge

I am trying to merge a new version into the release branch. I got about 38 conflicts and I sort of get rid of them by selecting the file and clicking the third button at the bottom center saying to use the right file for the merge.
Yet there are three files left: a .xib, the project.pbxproj and a normal .m file that whatever button I push the red C does not disappear and the merge button remains dimmed.

What must I do to also merge those files and thereafter merge the whole project?

Thanks,
Fabrizio

Comment: The *.m file I managed to fix by copying the file. Yet the fr localized storyboard kepis on producing conflict even if I deleted it. And also the c in the process does not go away and I do not know how may I fix this issue outside the merge as I did for the .m file.

Comment: I managed to merge it by replacing both the offending nib code and the project file. Yet the merged version gives error everywhere by not finding the method declarations but if I try to merge again it says there are no changes. According to git, thereafter, the programs are identical but one works and other does not even compile.

Answer (score 0):

File by file with a lot of work I fixed it. Surely if each time I need to merge two files I need an evening work, that is not a nice operation to execute!